# Detect shiftKey for mouse event on google maps v3 polygon

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, mouseevent, polygon

Is there a way to detect a shift-mouseclick on a polygon when using the google maps V3(.16) javascript API? 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MouseEvent

I do receive the mouse event, and I can see that the original event is wrapped in a google event class, which is just what's needed (Access the event.**Ua**.shiftKey property).

I found however that last month, google may have updated their api and now the property is renamed to event.**Pa**.shiftKey.

For reference, see https://i.stack.imgur.com/80npD.png for a screenshot of the event structure in the webinspector.
Is there any way to detect whether the shift key is pressed during a click on a google maps polygon using the event, and without having to rely on google-not-updating-their-api? What am I missing?

Thx!

Answer (score 5):

Using undocumented properties is almost always a bad idea. If you can *possibly* avoid it, avoid it. In this case, the API is probably being compressed with the Closure Compiler, and so the next time they update, it may not be `Pa` anymore either.

> Is there any way to detect whether the shift key is pressed during a click on a google maps polygon using the event, and without having to rely on google-not-updating-their-api?

#### If just `Ua` vs. `Pa`:

You could feature detect:

```
var shiftKey = (event.Ua || event.Pa).shiftKey;
```

That uses JavaScript's [curiously powerful `||` operator](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/javascripts-curiously-powerful-or.html) to reference the `Ua` property's value, if there is one and it's truthy, or the `Pa` property's value otherwise.

This assumes that when they change it from `Ua` to `Pa`, they don't use `Ua` for something else. If there's a chance of that, this more thorough version would do it:

```
var shiftKey = ((event.Ua && 'shiftKey' in event.Ua) ? event.Ua : event.Pa).shiftKey;
```

That specifically checks for a `Ua` object with a `shiftKey` property, falling back to `Pa` if not found.

#### If it could be anything

...you can search for it:

```
var shiftKey;
if (Object.keys(event).some(function(key) {
      if (event[key] && 'shiftKey' in event[key]) {
          shiftKey = event[key].shiftKey;
          return true;
      }
      return false;
  })) {
    // We found it, `shiftKey` has the value
} else {
    // We didn't find it
}
```

Side note: `Object.keys` is an ES5 feature present on all modern browsers. If you need to support older browsers like IE8, it can be polyfilled.

Comment: Thx! Didn't want to use something undocumented like looking for Ua, Pa or something else due to the closure compiler, but not having the shiftkey property is not an option. Searching for it is, if there's no alternative. Just seems an anti-solution to me, but if it works it works :)

Comment: Indeed, it looks as though the structure of the event object has changed completely now, making the approach above no longer useful

Answer (score 1):

I've just come across this problem (after noticing I couldn't just use window.event because Firefox doesn't support it)

[google.maps.mouseEvent](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#MouseEvent) has, as T.J. Crowder said, a property which contains keys such as `shiftKey`, `altKey`, etc. In the current release of google maps api, said property is `va`. So of course we can't use it because its name will change in the next release of so.

So my solution has been to iterate over the `google.maps.mouseEvent` parameter, checking its values so see which one of them is a valid [window.MouseEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent).

```
var newcircle= new google.maps.Circle({map:map, position:map.getCenter(), radius:1000});

google.maps.event.addListener(newcircle,'click',function(mouseEvent) { 
    var event = Object.values(mouseEvent)
        .filter(function (property) {
          return property instanceof window.MouseEvent;
        });

    if (event.length) {
      event = event[0];
    } else {
      event = {};
    }
    var shiftKey = event.shiftKey || false;
});
```

Funny enough, when I tried to use a marker for this example, there wasn't an instance of `window.MouseEvent` in the `google.maps.mouseEvent`.

Comment: Yeah it looks as though for Markers the property is not populated. If you step through the source code you'll see the Google Maps library creates a new MouseEvent and omits sending the original event alongside it.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up with a solution close to [amenadiel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46799101/5503625). I thought it would be better not to relay on all the possible uglified variable names, but to look for the one being a `MouseEvent` and use that one to check for the `shiftKey` property, like this:

```
function polygonListener(polygonEvent) { 
  var shiftKey = false;
  for(var i in polygonEvent){
    if(polygonEvent[i] instanceof window.MouseEvent){
      shiftKey = polygonEvent[i].shiftKey;
      break;
    }
  }
  // Rest of the code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone is still looking how to get the `MouseEvent` from a google maps event, this is the method I've been using.

```
const mouseEvent = Object.values(event).find(p => p instanceof window.MouseEvent);
// then do whatever with the MouseEvent
const shiftKey = mouseEvent.shiftKey;
```