# How to detect whether shift was pressed during onclick handler?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-events

I have the handler:

```
myObj[id] = new google.maps.Circle({/*Initialization*/}
myObj[id].addListener('click', function (event) {
     //Some code here
 myFunction(this, event);
}
```

And the function that does not work.

```
myFunction(elem, event) {
    console.log(event);
    if(!event.shiftKey) { //Do Something }
}
```

As you can see from the image below, the `qZ` object has the `Aa` *Attribute?* which is responsible for the `MouseEvents`, right ?

[image: Errors]

Well, if I change my function to:

```
myFunction(elem, event) {
    if(!event.Aa.shiftKey) { //Do Something }
}
```

It works. The problem is, this `Aa` once were `Va` and `Xa` before that. I can't keep chaning all the time. I have no idea why this happens nor how to fix it.

It's detecting the `click` is calling the function normally, but the shiftKey is ignored. How could I detect the `shiftKey` on `click` event ?

#### Update:

Following the tip gave by Dan, I tried this to loop through the object and try to find the `shiftKey`:

```
var shiftKey;
      if (Object.keys(event).some(function (key) {
            if (event[key] && 'shiftKey' in event[key]) {
                  shiftKey = event[key].shiftKey;
                  return true;
            }
            return false;
      })) {
            // We found it, `shiftKey` has the value. Do nothing
      } else {
            //If no shiftKey is pressed execute my code!
      }
```

But now it never execute my code that should be trigger when shiftKey is NOT pressed...

Comment: What framework is addListener?

Comment: Sorry, I think that I don't quite understand your question. Not using any framework.  It detects the click but ignores the shiftKey.

Comment: I would expect `addEventListener` not `addListener`. I am not sure where you are getting `addListener` from

Comment: @epascarello My bad ! Updated the question with more information.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect shiftKey for mouse event on google maps v3 polygon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28196026/detect-shiftkey-for-mouse-event-on-google-maps-v3-polygon)

Comment: +1 cuz now I finally understand that the source of this change is from googleMaps itself.  I did it and it it always run the same piece of code, with or without keyShift pressed.

Answer (score 0):

From your update I see a mistake:

```
var shiftKey;
      if (Object.keys(event).some(function (key) {
            if (event[key] && 'shiftKey' in event[key]) {
                  shiftKey = event[key].shiftKey;
                  return true; // <- should be return shiftKey
            }
            return false;
      })) {
            // We found it, `shiftKey` has the value. Do nothing
      } else {
            //If no shiftKey is pressed execute my code!
      }
```